# Styling ListView in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977704/styling-listview-hovered-selected-state-for-universal-windows-platform) question + answer to my problem here on stackoverflow, but for me its not totally clear where to change the

```
ListViewItemPresenter
```

I tried many things, but it seems like I cant find it on my own :(

Here is my XAML code for this frame:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemListDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:Item">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Name="image" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" />
            <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Name="NameTextBlock"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" Name="DescriptionTextBlock"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Price}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="26" Name="PriceTextBlock"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="€" FontSize="26" Name="Currency" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemListDataTemplate}"
              >
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Can someone help me our please? Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to edit `ListViewItemPresenter` in your Page:

1. You can copy the XAML Template from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) (the first XAML codes block below **Default Style**). Add it to your `Page.Resources`. `ListViewItemPresenter` lies among those XAML codes, you can edit its Properties and this style will be applied to all the items of this page's ListView. **Notes:** don't add `x:Key` to this style.
2. Add a `ListViewItem` Control to your Page like below:

   ```
   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
       <ListViewItem></ListViewItem>
   </Grid>
   ```

   Document Outline->Select ListViewItem->Edit Template->Edit a Copy:
   [image]

Remove the `x:Key` Property of generated Style Resource, so that this style will be applied to all ListViewItem. Then you can edit the `ListViewItemPresenter` in the generated XAML Resource.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your DataTemplate inside of the Listview.

Put it in the ItemTemplate property.

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" 
        IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Image Name="image" Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="150" />
            <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" Name="NameTextBlock"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" Name="DescriptionTextBlock"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Price}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="26" Name="PriceTextBlock"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="€" FontSize="26" Name="Currency" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>     
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```